# Commctl.h missing

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to include : `#include <commctl.h>` into my win32 API program; however, it looks like it does not exist.

What is the problem ?

Comment: Also, please have a look at this article on Visual Styles, CommCtrl and manifests: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `CommCtrl.h`?

```
#include <commctl.h>
```

And it should be located in your platform SDK folder or visual studio includes.

Example:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include